# Cant connect S3 with CM 10.2 to adb

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-3, adb

I cant get to use adb with my S3 in Windows 7. I am using CM 10.2, when I run `adb devices` nothing is shown. I also tired `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server`

I tried in Ubuntu and worked perfectly. I would use Ubuntu if I could but the windows pc is the one at the office.

What do I need to do for it to work?

Comment: You're almost certainly missing the right USB drivers on your Windows machine ([not an issue with Ubuntu](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/51331/156)). See [USB drivers for using ADB with Samsung Galaxy S on CyanogenMod](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15042/).

Answer (score 1):

Finally the issue was missing drivers, the solution was to use the ones that come with the sdk but using another winusb file.

Here you can find the file that did the trick. https://github.com/gu1dry/android_winusb

Just replace the file with the one downloaded and install drivers as described in the android doc.